# Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_1: expected shape=(None, 244, 720, 3), found shape=(None, 720, 3)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I wanted to test my model by uploading an image but I got this error. And I think I got the error somewhere in these lines, I'm just not sure how to fix.

```
IMAGE_SIZE = [244,720]
inception = InceptionV3(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + [3], weights='imagenet',include_top=False)
```

Also here's the code of uploading my test image

```
picture =  image.load_img('/content/DSC_0365.JPG', target_size=(244,720))
img = img_to_array(picture)
prediction = model.predict(img)
print (prediction)
```

I'm still a newbie in Machine learning so my knowledge right now is not yet that deep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mostly because you didn't prepare your input (its dimension) for your inception model. Here is one possible solution.

---

**Model**

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import *

IMAGE_SIZE = [244,720]
inception = InceptionV3(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + [3], 
                         weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# check it's input shape 
inception.input_shape
(None, 244, 720, 3)
```

**Inference**

Let's test a sample by passing it to the model.

```
from PIL import Image 

a = Image.open('/content/1.png').convert('RGB')
display(a)
```

[image]

Check its basic properties.

```
a.mode, a.size, a.format
('RGB', (297, 308), None)
```

So, its shape already in (`297 x 308 x 3`). But to able to pass it to the model, we need an extra axis which is the batch axis. To do that, we can do

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 

a = tf.expand_dims(np.array(a), axis=0)
a.shape
TensorShape([1, 308, 297, 3])
```

Much better. Now, we may want to normalize our data and resize it according to the model input shape. To do that, we can do:

```
a = tf.divide(a, 255)       
a = tf.image.resize(a, [244,720])  
a.shape
TensorShape([1, 244, 720, 3])
```

And lastly, pass it to the model.

```
inception(a).shape
TensorShape([1, 6, 21, 2048])

# or, preserve the prediction to later analysis 
y_pred = inception(a)
```

## Updated

If you're using the [`[tf.keras]`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/load_img) image processing function which loads the image into PIL format, then we can do simply:

```
image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img('/content/1.png', 
                                             target_size=(244,720))
input_arr = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
input_arr = np.array([input_arr])  # Convert single image to a batch.

inception(input_arr).shape
TensorShape([1, 6, 21, 2048])
```

Comment: Thanks, Sir! I'll edit my code and I'll update you after I get the results.

Comment: It worked. :) But to add, how can I insert that resized image into my code for predicting the image (code is stated in my updated post)?

Comment: picture =  image.load_img('/content/DSC_0365.JPG', target_size=(244,720))
img = img_to_array(picture)
prediction = model.predict(img)
print (prediction)

Comment: that was my previous code. How can I insert the resized image in there?

Comment: When you specify target size with [`tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/load_img), it will resize the image for you, so you don't need to use `tf.image.resize` here. Basically, keras uses PIL in the backend.

Comment: Oooh wow I see. Thank you, Sir! Problem solved. I appreciate your effort, more power! Have a good day!